# Android: Make size of tabs according to the text

Tags: android, android-tabs

I would like to ask whether there is a way to change the size of the tabs in the action bar according to the length of the text.

I have a very long tab and when it is its default size, the other tabs remaining with a lot of free space. Otherwise, the long title of the tab gets split into two rows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just set the android:layout_width to wrap_content of that tab in your xml-file. It's always usefull to paste some code of where your problem is here

Comment: Actually, I don't have code to show that will help, because I am using the ActionBar's Tabs and I am tryign to make a style that will make it working.

Comment: Ok, so set the width to wrap_content, so the tab will only use as much space as needed

Comment: It turned out that the tabs in the ActionBar have to be the same size, I couldn't find a way to use the styles in the style.xml to make them different even a with custom view for each tab.